# Confirming convergence of a sequence and finding its limit.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

The problem I'm working on (from Rudin) is the following.

> If $s_1=\sqrt{2}$ and $$s_{n+1} = \sqrt{2+\sqrt{s_n}} \quad\text{      } (n=1,2,3,\cdots)$$
>
> prove that $\{s_n\}$ converges and that ${s_n}<2
> $ for $(n=1,2,3,\cdots)$.

The following is what I tried to do.

a), I can see that the sequence is monotonically increasing. So if I could see if it is bounded, then the sequence must be convergent. The problem is, I cannot confirm the part that it is bounded. I though about the sequence $$\{t_n\} = \{ \sqrt{2},\sqrt{4},\sqrt{6},\cdots\}$$ which is clearly "larger" than $\{s_n\}$ , but this is not bounded. Can someone help me out ?

b), I am also trying to find the limit. Assuming that convergence were confirmed, can someone tell me how to work on this ? The following is what I tried but it seems to not work well...

$$x = \sqrt{2+\sqrt[4]{2+\sqrt[4]{2+\cdots}}} $$ 
$$x^2 - 2 = \sqrt[4]{2+\sqrt[4]{2+\sqrt[4]{2+\cdots}}}$$ 
$$x^2 - 2 = \sqrt{x}$$
$$(x-1)(x^3+x^2-3x-4)=0$$

It's clear why $x=1$ is not the solution here, so $x$ must be one of the three solutions that the cubic has as a root. Besides the fact that I cannot do anything simple to find the solution of the cubic since it is irrational, did I at least proceed in a right way?

How would you solve this problem ?

The book implies that the upper bound of $\{s_n\}$ is $2$, but how is it confirmed ?

Edit:
Thanks everyone, for the help. I just need someone to confirm how to find the limit.

Comment: If you want to prove that the upper bound is 2, use a simple proof by induction: $s_1< 2$, assuming that $s_n< 2$, one knows that $s_n+2<4$ and by taking square roots $\sqrt{s_n+2}<2$ which is the same as $s_{n_1}<2$.

Now, we know that the limit exists (as you already have established that the sequence is monotonically increasing), let $s=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} s_n$ and note that $s=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} s_{n+1}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{s_n+2}=\sqrt{2+\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}s_n}=\sqrt{2+s}$ using that $\sqrt{}$ is continuous. From this, you can calculate $s$.

Comment: It seems like my way sounds good then. It was very helpful !

Comment: Sorry, I just saw that I used the wrong sequence ($s_{n+1}=\sqrt{2+s_n}$ instead of yours) but I still think you can adapt my comment to your sequence.

And yes, your way of finding the limit is the right one and note that there are formulas for finding the solutions of cubic equations. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Roots_of_a_cubic_function)

Comment: I am aware of the cubic formulas, but thanks. I was just trying to see if at least I were in the right direction. By the way, I would give you the check mark if you gave me an answer instead of a comment, so if you are interested.

Answer (score 1):

Induction. $n=1$ is obvious. 
$$
s_{n+1} = \sqrt{2+\sqrt{s_n}} < 2 \iff 2+\sqrt{s_n} < 4 \iff s_n<4
$$

Then your bounded + monotonic $\implies$ convergent logic is good.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It's really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

By Induction you can show that $s_n<2,\forall n\in N$.

Hint: $s_{n+1}=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{s_n}}\le \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}<\sqrt{2+2}=2$

Comment: Thank you ! It must be a common question because everyone says the same thing.